# Get state of a child component

Tags: reactjs

I am using [react-draggabe](https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable). I like the idea of adding functionality to a child component by wrapping it into another like `<Draggable>` does.
This component manages its own state which is cool. This way I dont have to care about anything.

However: I need to get the current position of the dragged element when an event occurs (e.g. user clicks a button somewhere in another child component).
I know I could use the onStop-handler and save the new position in the state of the parent elemet. But thats a problem: I duplicate the state of the draggable component because I also save it in the parent. I dont want to do that.

What is the react-way of doing this?
I am new to rect and this thinking so I would be thankful for a good explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html):

```
var Foo = React.createClass({       
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.refs.bar.baz) // "qux"  
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Bar ref="bar"  />
      </div>
    );      
  }
});



var Bar = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {baz: 'qux'};
  }
});
```

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/53866/) for you with an example of accessing state form a child component. There one component increments a value, and it's sibling component renders it, accessing this value via `props`/`refs` from their parent component.

Comment: Looks like a good solution for parent->child relation but gets complicated when you have parent->grandchild and deeper. However: This solves my problem in an elegant way. Thank you!

Comment: For these more complicated scenarios I guess you would want to use a state management library, like Redux or Mobx.

Comment: Yes, since you've mentioned that you don't need to pass data too deep in components tree, I've suggested you the easiest solution. If things get complicated, you can use stores or `context` (not recommended, it's an experimental feature).