# is it possible to set parents state by getting value from child?

Tags: reactjs

i tried setting state of parent by getting value from child, unfortunately i am getting error saying setState in not a function in parent component.

App.js

```
class App extends Component{
  state={
    data:{name:''}
  }
  getName(name){
    this.setState({data:{name:name}});
  }
  render(){
    const {data}=this.state;
    return(
      <div>
       <h2>Name : </h2>{data.name}
        <MyName getName={this.getName}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

MyName.js

```
class MyName extends Component{
  state={
    data:{name:''}
  }
  onChange = (e, {name, value }) =>
    this.setState({ data:{ name: value} },() => {
      this.props.getName(this.state.data);
  })

  render(){
    const {data}=this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
          <input 
            type='text'
            value={data.name}
            onChange={this.onChange}
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

is it possible to do so, if possible can anyone tell me how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get state of a child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126595/get-state-of-a-child-component)

Comment: Your event handlers are not bound to `this`. See [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for details. You need to add either a constructor in your components where you bind them or you use the "class field syntax": `getName = event => {/* handle event */}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<MyName getName={this.getName}/>
```

to

```
<MyName getName={name => this.getName(name)}/>
```